# My brother and his cipher

Tags: cipher

**NOTICE: true story ahead, you can skip it if you want and go straight to the puzzle**

I was reading a book when a scrap of paper fell out. Looking at it, I realised that there was a code on it. Now before you get all excited about hidden treasure and stuff, I instantly recognised my brother's handwriting. After attempting to crack the code, and failing, I asked him for the answer. I did get *extremely* close to cracking it though! Anyways, here's the code:

[image]

Text version:

> Can opens Incca lass orel case

---

**Note:**
The only important part is the text version; that's all you need to solve it.

---

**Hints:**

> My brother is ten.

Also how did I come close to cracking it? I noticed that some parts of the code seemed like words, for example saying it out loud makes it seem *almost* intelligible.

Comment: My guess (assuming those are all real words): replace each word with the word $n$ places before/after it in a dictionary, for some value of $n$. If I knew what dictionary to use, I'd try it.

Comment: Good guess, but it shouldn't require a dictionary to solve.

Comment: Can I confirm (as I spot many words) that this is a **3-9-16-8-5-18** (using digits) and not a **3-16-4-5** (again using digits)?

Comment: What's the difference between them? I am presuming you mean 3-15-4-5

Comment: Thanks with 15 not 16! A 3-9-16-8-5-18 is a symbol-by-symbol translation, a  3-15-4-5 is a word-by-word translation.

Comment: I guess it's a 3-9-16-8-5-18 then.

Comment: @Wen1now Is there any trivial cipher technique involved here? If yes, has the technique being clued in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you simply...

> Remove the 3 ca's in the sentence. So:
> [Ca]n opens Inc[ca] lass orel [ca]se = ***No pens in class, or else!***
> Which does sound like something a school teacher might say. Some classes only allow pencils. 
> And I did find it when I said it all out loud and noticed the middle part sounds like 'in class'.