# 3 letter word that rhymes with its reverse

Tags: word, rhyme

Find a non-palindromic three letter word* that rhymes with its reverse (which is also a word*). Do there exist other words that satisfy this property of different lengths?

---

*common english word

<sub>This is yet another [puzzle from my brother](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49007/my-brother-and-his-cipher)</sub>

Comment: Should have posted 2 minutes earlier to get your hat :P

Comment: @boboquack Which hat?

Comment: The 7 o'clock somewhere one - Hero of Time. You don't have it on Puzzling yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think I've got it:

> War and raw

Pronounced:

> /w**ɔː**/ and /r**ɔː**/

Comment: Not in my accent! I spent a while thinking about this and forgot that you two are Australian.

Comment: @Deusovi Care to tell us how you pronounce them? I'm curious.

Comment: As a suggestion for *any* puzzle that hinges on pronunciation, you should always listen to what online pronunciation tools say for those words—regional differences can be quite, um, *pronounced*.  In particular, Merriam Webster (http://m-w.com) offers pronunciations for most entries that are more or less "General American": the notional neutral or unaccented American pronunciations of words. Likewise, Googling "define <foo>" will commonly include a widget that gives a neutral accent pronunciation. Either one is for many Americans (myself included) pretty close if not exactly how we say things.

Comment: @Rubio Thanks! I copied straight from Google's `define:***` in either case, so unless google.com.au's pronunciation is Australianised, it should be what you get in America too.

Comment: Actually I believe Google pronunciation is localized if you don’t use google.com explicitly. I recommend m-w.com for that reason.